# Editing a question doesn't pop it high in the question list anymore?

Tags: support, edits, tag-watching, bump, interesting-page

I'm wondering if this a new change in SO.

[This question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749854/compiler-not-calling-appropriate-generic-overload-when-passed-with-value-type) was asked 7 hours ago. I edited it twice now. Both the times I couldn't see it popped up in the SO question list. Previously whenever I edited a question or answer it used to be shown high up in the list. This is not happening with my question at all. What can I do to seek more attention? No I haven't changed my favorite tags.

<sub>I'm looking at the list at www.stackoverflow.com. The main thing. The "interesting" tab.</sub>

Comment: Were you looking at the "Newest" list instead of the "active" list?

Comment: @Servy not all. I'm seeing at www.stackoverflow.com. The main thing. The "interesting" tab..

Comment: People actually use the homepage to find questions?

Comment: @Servy isn't there were your favourite questions, the most recently active questions queue up? The "newest" questions are for most recently "asked" questions, isnt it?

Comment: The most recently active questions queue up on the *active* tab.

Comment: People asking questions aren't looking for other people's questions, people looking to answer questions are generally going to be looking at one of a few tags.  The homepage has too many questions from too broad of a range to be particularly useful...

Comment: @Servy according to the tags you have "favourited" the homepage only lists questions that may interests you. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @nawfal Those questions will be highlighted, but the rest are still there..

Comment: @Servy I dont think so. When I add android to my list, I can see my homepage littered with android questions. if i take it off, I see C# questions mainly, which i have favourited.

Comment: @Servy nawfal is looking at the "interesting" tab, not [so/questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). There's only a small subset of all questions that make it to "interesting".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's going on with [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14749854/3)?  Although you seem to be adding clarifying information to the question, you also appear to be *asking a new question.*  Stack Overflow doesn't work this way; you can't expect to engage the entire Stack Overflow community in a lengthy ongoing discussion about a single post.

In short, if your focus is on getting additional attention by bumping your question, and milking it for additional information by changing the question being asked, you're probably doing it wrong.

After a couple of days, if you still need a more comprehensive answer to your question, [post a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).  This will move the question to the "featured" page, and give it more exposure.

Note: Where your question actually winds up on the front page after a bump is determined by a non-trivial algorithm that is [described here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes), and it's probably been tweaked since then.

Comment: Your point 1 is not true. The rest is, though.

Comment: Thanks. But do you think my update should be a separate question?

Comment: @nawfal No, your update should *not* be a separate question. If you have a separate question, post a separate question, after searching to see if it's already asked.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks, I'll offer bounty once I can..

Comment: @balpha: Well, *something* rates the question for relative bumping merit. Edited questions don't automatically get moved to the top of the list; that's verifiable by simple observation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes they do. The sort by "active" just sorts by the question's LastActivityDate, which is set on every normal edit (not counting the 5-minute quick edit).

Comment: @balpha: OK, but what about the front page (which is what most everyone uses, and is what I was originally referring to)?  That it gets sorted on the "active" page by most recent activity seems self-evident.

Comment: @balpha: Never mind, found this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/